# Can't click on XML preview in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Occasionally when I am using Android Studio the XML preview that appears on the right hand side of the window seems to lock. It isn't freezing because it updates like normal any time I make an edit the the XML. I just can't click on anything inside it.

Like I said, this happens occasionally and will randomly start working again and I have no idea what I did to change it.

Currently using Android Studio 3.1.4

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- First I had the same problem. Then I chose a different device. I saw the error window with the ability to click "rebuild and clean your project".
- Second Invalidate Caches/Restart

it worked. Try it.